# Boundary smooth like in Recap Photo

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I'm fairly new to Blender. I'm wondering, does anyone know if a tool in blender that does what the Smooth Boundary tool does in Autodesk Recap Photo? This tool allows you to select a boundary edge on an object that is jagged mesh triangles and it will then modify the edge to make it smooth. If Blender doesn't have a tool, does anyone know how to achieve the same result in Blender?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The smooth vertex tool might provide the help that you wish for.  It is on the tool panel (type "t" to open) under the "tools" tab (view first image).[image: SmoothVertex]

You can then edit how the amount it smooths it and how many times to repeat the process.  (view second image).[image]
You can also decide which axis it uses to smooth the vertices.  You do this by checking/unchecking the boxes underneath the smoothing settings (green circle on second image).

This may be what you wanted, and it may not.  If this did not help, please let me know, and I will do my best to help you.  Best of luck!